# How to delete outliers of a specific column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'd to delete some outliers from my dataframe

| Product | Brand | Year | calcium_100g | phosphorus_100g | iron_100g | magnesium_100g |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Poduct A | Brand A | 2020 | 8 | 50 | NaN | NaN |
| Poduct B | Brand A | 2021 | 54 | -1 | NaN | 17 |
| Poduct C | Brand C | 2020 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| Poduct D | Brand C | 2018 | NaN | 50 | 80 | NaN |
| Poduct E | Brand E | 2019 | 123 | 50 | NaN | 27 |

Outliers I'd like to delete are values bigger than 100 and below 0 from columns ending by "_100g" (-1 and 123) in that case.

I found a way to filter columns ending by "_100g"

```
Columns100g = list(data.filter(like='_100g', axis = 1).columns)
```

But at this point I can't find a way to delete my outliers.

Comment: I'm gonna calculate a filed ratio per column and delete columns with a ratio below to 90%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your `Columns100g`, you can use a for-loop to filter multiple columns:

```
for col in Columns100g:
    data = data[(data[col].fillna(0)>=0)&(data[col].fillna(0)<=100)]
```

Edit: But if you want to change outlier values to NaN, you can simply do:

```
data[(data[Columns100g]<0)|(data[Columns100g]>100)] = np.nan
```

Output:

```
    Product    Brand  Year  calcium_100g  phosphorus_100g  iron_100g  magnesium_100g  
0  Poduct A  Brand A  2020           8.0             50.0        NaN   NaN
1  Poduct B  Brand A  2021          54.0              NaN        NaN   17.0
2  Poduct C  Brand C  2020           NaN              NaN        NaN   NaN
3  Poduct D  Brand C  2018           NaN             50.0       80.0   NaN
4  Poduct E  Brand E  2019           NaN             50.0        NaN   27.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the [`drop()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) method which accepts `index` to remove the rows, and to use [`lt(0)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lt.html) and [`gt(100)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.gt.html) to get those indexes to be removed using `|` (or) and `any(1)` which would return `True` for any condition being satisfied for any column in the selected ones:

```
# Columns that have '_100g'
c = df.filter(like='_100g').columns

# Drop the rows above / below your threshold
new = df.drop(df[
    df[(df[c].lt(0)) | (df[c].gt(100))
       ].any(1)==True].index)
```

Prints back:

```
print(new)

    Product    Brand  Year  ...  phosphorus_100g  iron_100g  magnesium_100g
0  Poduct A  Brand A  2020  ...             50.0        NaN             NaN
2  Poduct C  Brand C  2020  ...              NaN        NaN             NaN
3  Poduct D  Brand C  2018  ...             50.0       80.0             NaN

[3 rows x 7 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas have a function name drop that you can use alongside the filter code you wrote.

```
    # Deleting columns
# Delete the "_100" column from the dataframe
data = data.drop("_100", axis=1)

# alternatively, delete columns using the columns parameter of drop
data = data.drop(columns="_100")

# Delete the _100 column from the dataframe in place
# Note that the original 'data' object is changed when inplace=True
data.drop("_100", axis=1, inplace=True). 

# Delete multiple columns from the dataframe
data = data.drop(["Y2001", "Y2002", "Y2003"], axis=1)
```

If you can replace the ones I wrote (_100) with your filter, you are good to go.
also, you can read more about the drop function in the link below:
https://www.shanelynn.ie/using-pandas-dataframe-creating-editing-viewing-data-in-python/